# I have 4 sets of two numbers [1x2]. How do I add each corresponding row?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here are the four [2x1] variables.

```
A1 =
0.5653
0.5648

phi1 =
5.3637
5.3951

A2 =
0.6063
0.6057

phi2 =
3.1646
3.1961
```

I need to add all rows together.

I wrote the function below

```
function [At] = somme_signaux(A, phi);
At=sum((A+phi));
end


[At] = somme_signaux([A1 A2],[phi1 phi2])
At =
2.3421   17.1195
```

The real answers are:

```
0.5653+5.3637+0.6063+3.1646 = 9.6999
0.5648+5.3951+0.6057+3.1961 = 9.7617
```

Comment: Just do `A1 + A2 + phi1 + phi2`?

Comment: Thanks suever, but I will eventually need to add more signals(A3, phi3), so I will need a function taking a variable number of signals.

Comment: Why would you need a separate function even in that case? You're still going to have to write out the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

function [At] = somme_signaux(A, phi)
At=sum(plus(A,phi),2);
end